# How sorting works in PHP? What algorithm is used?

Tags: php, sorting

How PHP `asort()` works? What algorithm is used for sorting? I am using `asort()` function to sort an `$array` but its not sorting as i wanted.

```
<?php
  $array = array("test","Travel","en");
  asort($array);
  var_dump($array); "test" }
?>
```

The var_dump() gives

```
array(3) { 
    [1] => string(6) "Travel" 
    [2] => string(2) "en" 
    [0] => string(4) "test" 
}
```

Comment: The algorithm used is a quicksort: see the `Note` in the [PHP Docs](http://php.net/sort)... and it's case-sensitive by default, so that's why `Travel` with an upper-case `T` comes before `en` with a lower-case `e`

Comment: The manual tells you what sorting algorithm is applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use flags to change the case sensitivity of the [`asort()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php).

```
$array = ["test", "Travel", "en"];
asort($array, SORT_FLAG_CASE | SORT_NATURAL);
var_dump($array);
```

These are documented with the [`sort()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php).

Answer (score 1):

you can try if `natcasesort(case insensitive)`  you want to sort in natural order:

```
<?php
  $array = array("test","Travel","en");
  natcasesort ($array);
  var_dump($array);
```

[DEMO HERE](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/704562b24117925a6a917c658736011c52862470)  & [Info here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natcasesort.php)

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly**, PHP uses an implementation of **Quicksort** 
**Secondly**, For more information go through **http://php.net/sort**

Note: agree with @miken32 answer